# Citus 10.2 not starting an instance of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, citus

I'm using RHEL 8.4 and I followed the installation instruction at [Set up a single-node Citus cluster on your own Linux machine from RPM packages.](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/installation/single_node_rhel.html).

Step 1 and 2 (**Install PostgreSQL 14 and the Citus extension** and **Initialize the Cluster**) went through without any issues.

But When I tried (Step 3: **Start the database server**)

`pg_ctl -D citus -o "-p 9700" -l citus_logfile start`

I got the following **error** in terminal

```
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

**The log output**

```
FATAL:  could not access file "citus": No such file or directory
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I do have a directory 'citus' in `postgres` user's home directory with all required files in it along with `postgresql.conf`

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you ran into one of 2 issues:

### Possible issue #1:

You did not successfully install citus package and the `citus.so` file is missing.

Can you see the file `/usr/pgsql-14/lib/citus.so` that should be installed via the package `citus102_14`?

If that is not the case, you should figure out why the package is not installed.

### Possible issue #2

You do not run `pg_ctl` command in the home directory of `postgres` user.

Comment: #1: I explored the contents of /usr/pgsql-14/lib and citus.so is present in the directory. #2: I am running pg_ctl as postgres user. Still I'm getting the error mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I am using the Postgres [compiled](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/install-short.html) from the source file. Thus, instead of

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-14-citus-10.2
```

I compiled the source of the Citus from [Github](https://github.com/citusdata/citus) and specified the path to location of my Postgres while configuring as:

`git clone https://github.com/citusdata/citus.git`

`cd citus`

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql/`

`make`

`sudo make install`

I do not get an error during `pg_ctl start` and I can load extension as `CREATE EXTENSION citus;`.